# Stencil Shader in Unity URP causes Camera (Default & AR) Output Blue

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, shader, vuforia, urp

EDIT
i get a blue camera output with **AR AND Default Scene Camera** working with Unity 2021.3.9f and Vuforia 10.14.4

I can use Unity URP and Vuforia as long as no special shaders are included. When i embed a stencil shader (follwed a tutorial "Impossible Geometry with Stencil Shaders in Unity URP" by Daniel Ilett)  i get a blue camera output. The setup is as follows:

1. write a stencil shader
2. in the inspector: create a new Layer "StencilLayer1"
3. put all object - affected by the shader - in the Layer "StencilLayer1"
4. put the Stencil Shader on the Stencil Object
5. go to the "URP Asset Renderer" in the Inspector. i applied the settings as described in the tutorial.

In Unitys Scene View the shader is working without problems. but as soon as i go to play i get a blue screen in the AR camera.

Trying to figure out which setting could be wrong, it happened, that as soon as i deactivate a "Filtering - LayerMask" in the "URP Asset Renderer" the Camera output is blue. What can i do to implement the stencil shader?

I really would appreciate any hint.
Best, milla

UPDATE: I went though the unityproject (provided on GitHub by Daniel Ilett) and changed one settings after the other. Everything works fine til importing the Vuforia package. neither the Main Camera nor the AR Camera do render the scene in Game view - just a blue camera image - in unity scene view everything is working properly.

in the export test on **android and ios** the camera happend to **work**. Now it would be interesting why the gameview cam is not able to render the scene. has anybody experienced the same? lg